# How to prevent my friends from seeing my friends’ list on Facebook

Tags: facebook, friends, friend-list

I am wondering, is there a way that enables me to customize how my friends in my friend list see each other on Facebook?

**There are some cases that make this feature so useful and necessary, for example:**

1. You add a new girl as a friend and don't want for her to see your other girl friends in your friends’ list.
2. You add your current manger and don't want for her/him to your ex manager in your friends’ list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a way.

1. Click the **Friends** tab on your timeline.
2. On the top right corner of **Friends** page you'll see two buttons: **Find Friends** and **Edit** (a pencil like button). Click on the **Edit** button and click **Edit privacy**.
3. The first option allows you to set who sees your friend list; set this to **Only me** and click **Close**.

Your friend list is only visible to you now. Note! Mutual friends will be visible to anybody in your friend list... meaning if your current manager is also a friend of your ex-manager, he/she will see the other in your friend list. Hope this helps.